# Fade loop glitch

Tags: arduino-uno, timers

I am working on a little sub program to run a PWM LED. I have a larger program that gives me a non-blocking 10 ms delay.

It mostly works well, but I get a -1 thrown during the code execution that causes my LED to flicker. Any insight into where this comes from or a better way to do this would be appreciated.

```cpp
int pulse = 9; // the PWM pin the LED is attached to
int pulsebrightness = 0; // how bright the LED is
int fadeAmount = 1; // how many points to fade the LED by
int holdpulseon = 0;
int holdpulseoff = 0;
int totalcycle = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(pulse, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println (" ");
  Serial.println ("Momentum Booting");
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  delay(10);

  analogWrite(pulse, pulsebrightness); // set the brightness of pin 9:
 
  if (holdpulseon == 0 && holdpulseoff == 0) {
    pulsebrightness = pulsebrightness + fadeAmount; // change the brightness for next time through the loop:
  }

  if (pulsebrightness <= 0 || pulsebrightness >= 255) { // reverse the direction of the fading at the ends of the fade:
    fadeAmount = -fadeAmount;
  }
  
  if (pulsebrightness == 0 ) {
    holdpulseon++;
    if (holdpulseon == 50) { // 50*10ms cycle
      holdpulseon = 0;
      Serial.print (holdpulseon);
      Serial.println (" hold on");
    }
  }

  if (pulsebrightness == 255) {
    holdpulseoff++;
    Serial.print (holdpulseoff);
    Serial.println (" hold off");
    if (holdpulseoff == 5) { // 5*10ms cycle
      holdpulseoff = 0;
      totalcycle++;
    }
  }

  constrain(pulsebrightness, 0, 255);
  Serial.println(pulsebrightness);
   
  if (totalcycle == 2) {
    delay (500000);
  }
}
```

```
0
0
0
0
0 hold on
0
-1
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: which line prints the -1?